# oracle stored procedure not working

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

the below procedure complies fine,

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1
          (v_MGR int,
          v_empid IN OUT int)
    AS
    BEGIN
    v_empid :=0;
    IF (v_mgr IS NOT NULL AND v_mgr <> '') then
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT EMPNO
          FROM EMP
       WHERE MGR = Rtrim(v_MGR)' into v_empid;
    END IF;
    END PROCEDURE1;
```

but when i run

```
DECLARE
  V_MGR NUMBER;
  V_EMPID NUMBER;
BEGIN
  V_MGR := 7902;
  V_EMPID := NULL;

  PROCEDURE1(
    V_MGR => V_MGR,
    V_EMPID => V_EMPID
  );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('V_EMPID = ' || V_EMPID);
END;
```

the output should be v_empid =2356

but its always showing v_empid = 0 please help to get proper answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Why is the `out` parameter is 0? Take a look at the `if` condition in the procedure

   ```
   IF (v_mgr IS NOT NULL AND v_mgr <> '')
   ```

   especially at its second part `AND v_mgr <> ''`. Oracle treats empty string `''` as `null` and any comparison to `null` leads to unknown result, thus the above `IF` condition always evaluates to false so `execute immediate` statement never executes and as a result the value of `v_empid` 
   will never be overwritten.
2. In this particular situation there is absolutely no need of using dynamic SQL(native dynamic sql `execute immediate`), because there is no dynamic construction of the query - table and columns are known at compile-time. You simply could use static sql instead:
3. If your query returns more than one row, you will hit `too_many_rows` exception. You either should guarantee that your query returns exactly one row, by including `rownum=1` in the `where` clause of the query(if there is a change of returning multiple rows) or you use a collection as the `out` parameter, to return the result set:

   ```
   create or replace type T_EmpNums is table of number;
   /

   create or replace procedure procedure1(
       v_mgr  int,
       v_emps out T_empnums
   )
   as
   begin
     if v_mgr is not null  
     then
        select empno
          bulk collect into v_emps
          from emp
         where mgr = v_mgr;
     end if;
   end;
   /

   declare
     v_mgr number;
     v_empids T_EmpNums;
   begin
     v_mgr := 7902;
     procedure1(v_mgr, v_empids);
     if v_empids is not empty
     then 
       for empno in v_empids.first .. v_empids.last
       loop
         dbms_output.put_line('v_empid = ' || to_char(v_empids(empno)));
       end loop;
     end if;
   end;
   ```

Comment: @itmitică `a = null` condition will never be evaluated to true regardless whether an empty string has been assign to the `a` variable or not. Do not confuse it with the fact that condition where we compare two empty strings directly (`''=''`) in PL/SQL, evaluates to true.

Comment: I agree. My point is that `a = null` is not the same with `a is null`. Here's a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bbbc6/1

Answer (score 1):

Well, you declare `v_MGR int` and then you go and test this `v_mgr <> ''` and use this `Rtrim(v_MGR)` in your condition.

Which is it, (var)char or number for mgr and v_mgr?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1
      (v_MGR int,
      v_empid IN OUT int)
AS
BEGIN
v_empid :=0;
IF (v_mgr IS NOT NULL AND v_mgr <> '') then
SELECT EMPNO into v_empid
      FROM EMP
   WHERE MGR = Rtrim(v_MGR) ;
END IF;
END PROCEDURE1;
```